# SpriteKit - how to spawn similar characters?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game I subclassed SKSpriteNode and added a spawn function:

```
class Character: SKSpriteNode {    
   func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint) {
      parentNode.addChild(self)
   }
}
```

Then, from GameScene.swift, I loop through an array and spawn a new character with each pass:

```
for _ in shuffledCharacterArray {
   let wrongCharacter = Character()
   wrongCharacter.spawn(parentNode: self, position: shuffledPositionArray)
}
```

The ridiculous thing is that everything works. What I don't get is why. It seems that with each loop in the array I'm creating the same wrongCharacter instance over and over. So, my question is, is this considered the 'right' way to create many instances?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would not work?

Comment: It seems wrong because I’m using the same instance variable name for dozens of instances. I thought that each instance needed a unique name.

Comment: The name `wrongCharacter` is just an identifier at compile time. At runtime, all the nodes are referenced by their parent nodes at different memory addresses. They don't need to have unique names. As I suggested, you should probably put your sprite nodes in a collection of some sort, like an array. That way you can easily refer to each of the sprites. In the case of an array, you can use indices to access the sprites.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems, it seems.

First, you are not using the second argument of the `spawn` method. If what you have shown here is the whole method body, you should probably remove that parameter or make use of it.

Second, you seem to be passing an array to a parameter that accepts a `CGPoint`. Are you sure that `shuffledPositionArray` is a `CGPoint`?

Third, you don't seem to be adding the `Character` nodes into some kind of collections like an array. If you want to have access to the characters later on, you should probably add them to an array:

```
// I don't know why you are iterating through shuffledCharacterArray and ignoring each element, so I changed it to loop 10 times here.
for _ in 0..<10 {
    let character = Character()
    character.spawn(parent: self, position: ...)
    characters.append(character) // <----
}
```

Regarding your question of whether adding sprites like this is "right", I would say that I have never seen people do it like this before. Most people I've seen do it like this:

```
let character = Character()
self.addChild(character)
```

If you do it another way, readers of your code might be confused for a second and might have to look into how `spawn` is implemented to understand what you are doing. However, in this case, I think `spawn` is a descriptive enough name.

Comment: The code was only meant to highlight the fact that I’m using the same instance variable name for many instances. I see now how the partial code was misleading. I will fix it.

Comment: @squarehippo10 But do you get my point? Variable names don't matter at runtime. What's important is you should have a way to access the nodes you've created. I suggest you put them in an array.

Comment: Storing the instances in an array makes perfect sense, thanks. I'm still trying to wrap my head around "variable names don't matter at runtime." Last question - say I'm only using UIKit and not SpriteKit. If I tried to create several instances of a class using the same instance variable, I would have problems, right?  It just seems like creating instances should be the same for UIKit or SpriteKit. Though I suppose that creating nodes in SpriteKit is a different process.

Comment: How do you "create several instances of a class using the same instance variable"? @squarehippo10

Comment: Variable names are independent of the actual instances not only in UIKit as well, but all of programming.  The only time you have a problem with variable names is when you have multiple variables of the same name in the same scope of code.  If it's unique within a loop or function, it works like Sweeper described in any library or language.

Comment: I would point out, though, that putting SpriteKit nodes in a collection of some kind is only necessary under very specific circumstances.  Most of the time, you'll be referencing them either by UI interaction (touches), physics (collision), location (proximity to another node) or the like.  If you want a specific node, say the SpriteNode of the player's character, you'd utilize node.name, as SpriteKit has a robust name search feature.  Collections would only be when names & traits are inappropriate.  Arrays would only be used when you need an ordered collection.